# The disk drive for /boot/efi is not ready yet or not present

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

> and afterward partitioning with the kde partitionmanager said "there
>   are always 4 primary partitions on this device.

I think i made a failure as i first installed kubuntu as i made just
partition by partition, so that at least i have more then 4 primary 
partitions instead of the needed amount of primary partitions.
What brings me to my first question: how many primary partitions can
a linux installation generally have?
How can i move primary partitions to the extended partition so that
the needed /boot/efi-partition can be added into the primary field.

OS is Kubuntu 12.2 LTE

Ihr könnt mir auch in deutsch antworten

Comment: If you have a newer system with UEFI, you can boot in UEFI mode or BIOS mode. But if drive is MBR(msdos) you can only boot in BIOS mode. With gpt partitioning Windows only boots in UEFI mode. And with gpt partitioning you can boot Ubuntu in BIOS mode or UEFI mode. gpt has a (soft) limit of 128 (all primary) partitions. And in MBR you do not create an efi partition. Post this sudo parted -l

Comment: The question was how many partitions can be added by system limits and how to add the needed efi partition to the drives primary table. Thank you

Comment: Actually, it is possible to boot in EFI mode from an MBR disk, at least on some EFIs. The Ubuntu installer doesn't support this configuration, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if the solution for which you're asking (how to convert primary partitions into extended partitions) is the appropriate one for your system, or if it's even possible on your system.

The `/boot/efi` mount point is generally used by the EFI System Partition (ESP), which in turn is used only on EFI-based computers. Thus, it sounds as if you've probably got an EFI-based computer, although that's not 100% certain based on the evidence you've presented.

As oldfred says in his comment to your question, EFI-based computers generally boot with GPT disks, and GPT doesn't have the primary/extended/logical partition types; there are just 128 (by default) partitions on a disk. Thus, if you've got a GPT disk, it's impossible to convert from primary to logical partitions, since your existing partitions are neither primary nor logical (although they're more like MBR primary partitions in most respects), and GPT doesn't support logical partitions.

OTOH, if the `/boot/efi` issue is a red herring, you might have an MBR disk. In this case, you can use [FixParts,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) which is installed as part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu, to convert from primary to logical, with some caveats, as described on the FixParts Web page. Even in this case, though, it's not clear that converting primary to logical or vice-versa is really the best thing to do; a better description of the problem is necessary to offer advice.

If you want a better answer, you'll have to post more information. The output of `sudo parted -l`, as requested by oldfred, is a starting point. Still more information can be summarized by the [Boot Info Script;](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) run it and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates. Also, please describe precisely where you are and what's going wrong -- for instance, have you successfully installed Kubuntu but are having problems booting it, or is the installer failing, or are you able to boot but just get an error message during the boot process?